# Retrieve word(s) from characters using map

Tags: java, string, collections, hashmap, java-stream

I am trying to understand Collections and Stream.

I have split the sentence below and kept the position of each letter (I ignored space/blank):
"Hello Word!"

```
private static final String text = "Hello Word!";
static Map<String, List<Integer>> charsIndex = new HashMap<>();
static void charsIndex() {

        List<Character> charsList = text
                .chars()
                .mapToObj(e -> (char) e)
                .toList();
        System.out.println(charsList);

        int  position = 0;
        for (Character c : charsList) {
            if(!c.toString().isBlank()){
                charsIndex.computeIfAbsent(c.toString(),
                        addCharPosition -> new ArrayList<>()).add(position);
            }
            position += 1;
        }

        System.out.println(charsIndex);
}
```

Results:

> [H, e, l, l, o,  , W, o, r, d, !] (charsList)

> {!=[10], r=[8], d=[9], e=[1], W=[6], H=[0], l=[2, 3], o=[4, 7]} (charsIndex)

How can I sort the characters and rebuild my word along with the blank?

I try this way:

```
static void charsToString(){

  charsIndex.forEach((character, l) -> l.forEach(position -> {

  }));
}
```

Comment: have you considered using a StringBuilder, where you can set the characters to their right place?

Comment: From: `{!=[10], r=[8], d=[9], e=[1], W=[6], H=[0], l=[2, 3], o=[4, 7]}` 

To: `"Hello Word!"` @AlexanderIvanchenko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restore the original string based on the map of indices in the following steps:

- Sort the characters according to their positions. Because each entry in the map associates a character with multiple indices, for that you would need to define an auxiliary type, holding a reference to a single-char string and distinct position of this character. Let's call it `CharPosition`
- Generate a list of `CharPosition` (which is sorted).
- To restore the white spaces, we can define an array, having a length of the highest index + 1. Then populate this array with the contents of the `CharPosition` list.
- Finally, create a stream over the array elements, replace all null values with a white space and generate the resulting `String` using Collector [`joining()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining()).

For the purpose of conciseness, I'll use a [Java 16 record](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/language/records.html) to implement `CharPosition`:

```
public record CharPosition(String ch, int pos) {}
```

That's how the logic described above can be implemented:

```
static void charsToString() {
    
    List<CharPosition> charPositions = charsIndex.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
            .map(pos -> new CharPosition(entry.getKey(), pos))
        )
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(CharPosition::pos))
        .toList();
    
    int wordLen = charPositions.get(charPositions.size() - 1).pos() + 1;
    
    String[] word = new String[wordLen];
    
    charPositions.forEach(c -> word[c.pos()] = c.ch());
    
    String result = Arrays.stream(word)
        .map(str -> Objects.requireNonNullElse(str, " "))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
    
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

*Output:*

```
Hello Word!
```

Comment: The only thing I didn't understand is the point with the spaces. `int wordLen = charPositions.get(charPositions.size() - 1).pos() + 1;
    
    String[] word = new String[wordLen];`

Comment: @zartilas We can simply concatenate the character from the Map because it doesn't contain white spaces. Array allows us to arrange all these characters according to their initial positions. All unoccupied indices would be `null`, which means that they should be replaced with white spaces. `charPositions.get(charPositions.size() - 1).pos()` - is the index of the very last character. Therefore, array length should be `index + 1`, since arrays in Java are zero-based.